# Brisk (binary robust invariant scalable keypoints )

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst, brisk

I am trying to do BRISK  my own code in matlab.

Where ı am stack, ı don't understand what this expression means.

> let us consider one of the  N*(N −1)/2 sampling-point pairs (pi, pj).
>
> A = {(pi, pj) ∈ R2 × R2 | **i < N ∧ j < i ∧ i**, j ∈ N    }

The other my question , what is the difference between local gradient and global gradient?

Comment: To save you the trouble, there is a `detectBRISKFeatures` function in the Computer Vision System Toolbox: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/detectbriskfeatures.html

Comment: Thanks but ı have to write the my own  brisk code for my video-processing lesson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression means that you are looking at a pair of pixels (pi, pj), such that both pixels belong to the region R2 x R2, and the two pixels cannot be the same.

Gradient is a vector (Ix, Iy), where Ix is the first derivative in the x direction, and Iy is the first derivative in the y direction. This vector is defined at a point, so gradient is local by definition.  I don't know what global gradient means. More context may help here.

Comment: May ı ask what is the difference between  ( pj-pi )  and  ||  pj-pi ||  ?

Comment: I would guess that (pj-pi) is a vector from pi to pj, and ||pj-pi|| is the Euclidean distance between the two points.

Answer (score 0):

Given that we have set of points of size N. N*(N −1)/2 is N choose 2 which equals number of subsets of size 2 that can be taken from a set of size N ( a concept in probability called Combinations). Because you are working with pair of points you need subset size to be 2.

R refers to the set of all real numbers ( a single value). When it is squared it refers to the Cartesian plane, so pi is a pair of real numbers(x,y), a point in the Cartesian plane.

The character '^' is AND operation. So all the following conditions has to be satisfied:

1. the index i of the first point, pi, should be less than N
2. the index j of the second point must be less than the index of the first point.
3. Like i, j must also be less than N

Local gradient is computed locally on the pair of pixels pi and pj. while, global gradient is estimated for the region surrounding the keypoint by accumulating local gradients.